# Qual a conotação da palavra «nego»?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

Tenho uma amiga brasileira, que já conheço há algum tempo.
De vez em quando ela chama-me «nego». Suponho que queira dizer «negro». O engraçado é que sou branco. Qual a conotação/significado da palavra? Sempre que ela o diz, parece ser de forma carinhosa.

Comment: Provavelmente alguém te dará uma resposta mais completa, mas de fato é um apelido carinhoso que ouço bastante, embora tenha a impressão que seja um pouco regionalizado. Seria um equivalente a "meu querido(a)".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Em pt-BR, "meu nego" e "minha nega" são formas de tratamento extremamente **informais**, **amigáveis**, **íntimas**, e **até mesmo carinhosas**. Embora você possa ouvi-las ditas por qualquer um, é mais uma exclusividade de afro-descendentes e daqueles que habitam a periferia das grandes cidades da região sudeste e nordeste do Brasil.

O Priberam apresenta as seguintes definições para "nego" (substantivo masculino)

> - 1. (Brasil, Informal) - "diz-se de ou indivíduo de pele muito escura (negro)"
> - 2. (Brasil, Informal)  "forma familiar e carinhosa de tratamento" (ex.: cadê minha nega?).
> - 3. [Brasil, Informal]  "designação vaga de pessoa indeterminada" (ex.: isso aí é carro de nego trabalhador). = INDIVÍDUO, NEGUINHO, SUJEITO, TIPO

"nego", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/nego [consultado em 13-03-2017].

Obviamente a origem vem de "negro" e, inicialmente "meu nego" referia-se a "meu negro".  Hoje em dia pode ser dirigida a qualquer um independente de cor, **mas lembre-se: é informal e indica intimidade**, de modo que não se pode entrar em um restaurante e chamar o garçom de "meu nego" e nem dirigir-se a qualquer outro desconhecido dessa forma.

Casais afro-descendentes comumente dirigem-se um ao outro de forma carinhosa usando "meu/minha nego/a". Contudo, isoladamente, e **dependendo do contexto** e intonação, "nego/a" **pode ser um xingamento racista** principalmente quando dito por um branco e acompanhado de palavras adicionais, como por exemplo "seu nego imundo", "sua neguinha descarada".

"Nego/a" (assim como o diminutido "neguinho") é também um vocábulo usado com frequência por compositores de pagode, sambas de fundo de quintal, sambas partido-alto, e sambas-enredo de escolas de samba.

Além disso, de acordo com **a terceira definição do Priberam**, "nego", ou seu diminutivo "neguinho" são gírias que significam "alguém" "uma pessoa", "tem gente que" etc, como nos exemplos abaixo:

- "Não deixe nada a vista.  Senão **neguinho** vai passar por aqui e pegar tuas coisas"
- "**Nego** pensa que a gente é rico e tem dinheiro sobrando"

Nessas situações "nego" ou "neguinho" não vem precedido de artigo e nem de pronome indefinido.

Comment: Obrigado Centaurus. ;)

Comment: Obrigado. O cara com quem estou estudando capoeira treinou com "Nego Gato" ("Black Cat", me disseram) e eu não tinha certeza se ele se mudou para evitar "Negro" em seu nome enquanto estava nos Estados Unidos.

Answer (score 8):

O termo "nego", neste caso, não significa "negro", mas sim uma forma de tratamento mais carinhosa.
Uma forma comum de uso é "meu nego", que quer dizer "meu querido", "meu caro", "meu amigo", etc. E pode ser usado com qualquer pessoa, independente da cor da pele (desde que se tenha intimidade com a mesma)

Mas dependendo da forma como é usado, pode sim ser sinônimo de "negro", porém com uma conotação racista. Referir-se a uma pessoa como "aquele neguinho ali" (sendo que a pessoa em questão é negra) é considerado racista (sendo preferível dizer "aquele cara/moço/senhor" ou "aquela mulher/moça/senhora", dependendo do gênero da pessoa)

Existe ainda um outro uso: "nego" também é uma forma genérica e informal de se dizer "alguém".
Por exemplo, eu estou em uma fila, distraído, e não percebo que a fila andou. A pessoa que está atrás de mim poderia dizer:

> -Ei, presta atenção, senão nego vem e fura a fila.

Neste caso, "nego" seria uma forma de dizer "alguém". A frase significa que, se eu ficar distraído e não ver que a fila andou, alguém poderia entrar na minha frente.

PS: algumas pessoas argumentam que este último exemplo também pode ser considerado racista, já que pode dar a entender que somente negros furariam a fila. Já outras não fazem esta associação e entendem que "nego" é simplesmente uma forma informal de dizer "alguém". Polêmicas à parte, há pessoas que usam o termo desta forma, enquanto outras preferem trocá-lo por "cara", "sujeito" ou "alguém".

Comment: Obrigado Hugo ;)